# How to set the alignment and width of all cells of a large Handsontable?

Tags: handsontable

How to set the alignment and width of all cells the easy way?

Thanks.

Michael

Edit: Here my modified question - How to set the alignment and width of all cells of a large Handsontable? Is it possible to access all cells at once or to iterate over the cells?

Comment: What's 'the easy way'?

Comment: Ok, I meant to say "Is it possible to access all cells at once or to iterate over the cells?".

Comment: So you want to set the width of every cell in your entire table to be the same? Or on a per-column basis?

Comment: The width and the alignment of all cells.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to set the same width and same alignment for every cell in your table, then you simply want to add the following to your options object:

```
{
    "colWidths": 200,      // where 200 is an example width in pixels
    "className": "htRight" // this is an example; you can choose from 
                                  "htRight", "htLeft", "htMiddle", "htBottom", and "htTop"
}
```

If using a `type` other than `text`, the `text-align` property is given high priority. Therefore, to override this using CSS, you could add the following rule; this is an example on whatever `className` you used and assuming you want to stick it to the right.

```
.htCenter {
    text-align:right!important;
}
```

And at any point in your code, you can update these settings using `updateSettings()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but: width : Width of the grid. Can be a number or a function that returns a number, but I asked for the width of a cell -> colWidths is working for me. Regarding the alignment of cells I used  className: "htCenter" but this is not working because my cell type is numeric. It seems to be that the cell alignment is only working with cells of type string. I think in the future I have to improve my questions.

Comment: yes sorry, i meant to write `colWidths`, it's the same concept. As for the className, you could write CSS to manually force it to be centered, using the `!important` tag

Answer (score 0):

For the alignment, just add the the className parameter to the json instance

```
 var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    className: "htCenter",   //htCenter or htRight
 });
```